# Не могли бы объяснить в чём заключается задание, указатель на float это указатель на элемент вектора или на массив элементов?

Tags: c++

Создать абстрактный тип данных (КЛАСС) - вектор, который имеет указатель на float и число элементов. Определить функции: инициализации, удаления вектора, установки/ изменения размера,  доступа к элементам вектора, вычисления суммы элементов вектора. Для примера, в функции main, организовать поэлементное умножение двух векторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> вектор, который имеет указатель на float и число элементов

исходя из этого мне кажется, что имеется в виду указатель на массив `float`, т.е.

```
class MyVector {
    protected:
        float* m_data = nullptr; // непосредственно данные вектора
        int    m_size = 0;       // размер вектора

    public:
        // изменить размер вектора
        void resize(const int size) {
            // создать вектор нового размера
            float* new_data = new float[size];

            // скопировать данные
            for (int index = 0; index < min(size; m_size); index ++)
                new_data[i] = m_data[i];

            // заменить данные
            delete [] m_data;
            m_data = new_data;
        }    
}
```

думаю, что имелось в виду именно это

P.S.

в `resize` я конечно много чего не написал - типа проверки, что `m_data != nullptr`, обнуление нового массива и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
class Vector
{
    private:
        float * array;
        int     count;

...
```

`count` - количество элементов в массиве, на который указывает `array`.